# How can i add item(obj) to redux state in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I got an empty array whenever I am trying to add an item(obj). But when I am trying with useState the data is saved in an array but it's not saved along with another item (obj) it just adds the lastest clicked item basically I want to store the item in the state so that it can be used in other components

please correct what I am doing wrong thank you

```
 const handlecart=(item)=>{
    setCount(count+1)
    const data={name:item.name,image:item.image,price:item.price}
    dispatch(addingToCart(data))
    console.log(cart)
  }

 {localitem.map((product) => (
              <div key={product._id} className="group relative">
                <div className="w-full min-h-80 bg-gray-200 aspect-w-1 aspect-h-1 rounded-md overflow-hidden group-hover:opacity-75 lg:h-80 lg:aspect-none">
                  <img
                    src={product.image}
                    alt={"image"}
                    className="w-full h-full object-center object-cover lg:w-full lg:h-full"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-4 flex justify-between">
                  <div>
                    <h3 className="text-sm text-gray-700 font-semibold">
                      {product.name}
                    </h3>
                  <h4 className="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                    Price<p>{product.price}</p> 
                    ${product.price}
                  </h4>
                  </div>

                  <div className="px-3">
                    <button>buy</button>
                    <button onClick={()=>handlecart(product)}>cart</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
```

Comment: How does `addingToCart` look like ?

Comment: ` reducers: {
    addingToCart: (state, action) => {
      state.cart = action.payload;
    },
  },`

Comment: You seem to be using `useReducer`, there you can get the current state and the new element from the action and then just combine them as in: `[...state, newItem]`, if you share your reducer it might be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the return value in the above reducer, you are just overriding the `cart` in state with a single object. Ideally the cart is a list of items and whenever you add a item to the cart, you need to add it to the existing `cart` array.

```js
import {
  createSlice
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  cartItem: [],
}

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addingToCart: (state, action) => {
      const previousCart = [...state.cartItem];
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItem: [...previousCart, action.payload],
      };
    },
  },
});
export default cartSlice.reducer;

export const {
  addingToCart
} = cartSlice.actions;
```

Comment: by adding this got error with   state.cartItem is not iterable

Comment: This is just a trivial example of it can be done. But hard to really say what is going on without seeing the reducer that is being used.

Comment: `import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";`
    const initialState = {
      cartItem: [],
    }

`export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",

  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addingToCart: (state, action) => {
      const previousCart = [...state.cartItem];
      return {
        state: {
          ...state,
          cartItem: [...previousCart, action.payload],
        },
      };
    },
  },
});`

`export default cartSlice.reducer;
export const { addingToCart } = cartSlice.actions;``

Comment: @Dexter Check the updated snippet

Comment: sorry to reply so late but thanks @Sushanth that code works I see you have 10 yrs exp. in this field so can you tell me which is good I mean currently I am a fresher in full-Stack with react and node and there is a framework called Nextjs should I learn that too. I just want your opinion.

Comment: Glad it works. You are welcome. 
It all depends on what you are trying to achieve. nextJs performs server side rendering, because of which the first paint is really quick since most of the JS is computed on the server ( works out real well for static pages and heavy JS computations ). It is a wrapper on top of React framework. Does not hurt to lean though, but React by itself is easy to start out with.

Answer (score 0):

you can use unwrap to see what's going on, if your action is async.
like:
`dispatch(addingToCart(data)) .unwrap() .then((res) =>{ console.log(res} ) .catch(err => { console.log(err)}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).